# Cocoapods: Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Core`

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I have this in podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

but getting this error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Core`

i tried with `pod 'Firebase'` still can't find it.

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'caffetouch manager' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0.0'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator', '~> 2.0.1'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '~> 4.0.6'
    pod 'MZFormSheetPresentationController', '~> 2.4.2'
    pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 3.1.3'
    pod "GMStepper"
    pod 'DKImagePickerController', '~> 3.4.0'
    pod 'Siren', '~> 1.0.2'
    pod 'Eureka', '~> 2.0.0-beta.1'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 2.1'
    pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
    pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 4.0.5'
    pod 'SimpleAlert' '~> 2.0.1'

    pod 'BTNavigationDropdownMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/PhamBaTho/BTNavigationDropdownMenu.git', :branch => 'swift-3.0'
    pod 'ENSwiftSideMenu', :git => 'https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', git: "https://github.com/MLSDev/SkyFloatingLabelTextField.git", branch: "swift3"
end


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you add your whole pod file here for get exact idea.

Comment: updated @DarshanKunjadiya

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try to update pod repository

```
pod repo update
```

If doesn't help show log from

```
pod install --verbose
```

**Edit:**

try to add

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

to your Podfile. If doesn't help probably there is a problem with your local pod repo. You can fix this using:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: Genius - the last set of instructions solved the issue. Might have had something to do with Unity attempting to setup pods before I had a chance.

Comment: I also ran into this situation and fixed it by removing `Pods` and `Podfile.lock` then re-running `pod install`

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it helps. If you remove `Pods` folder and `Podfile.lock` you can also remove `workspace` file. It will be generated again

Comment: Denle una cheve a este campeon

Comment: How to add the source in terminal?

Comment: @Siva What do you mean by "add the source in the terminal"?

Answer (score 4):

try below commands:

```
pod repo remove master
pod repo update
pod install --verbose
```

Answer (score 4):

try to delete the file `podfile.lock`    
it helps with issue:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod
>   "Firebase/Core": 
>    In snapshot (Podfile.lock):  
>       Firebase/Core (= 4.8.1)

Comment: could you also please write what exactly deleting the lock file does? Can it have any side effects?

Comment: deleting pod lock file could potentially break project and might be catastrophic, as newer versions of pods might have changed. Doing this requires proper migration for each of the updated pod.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your podfile looks like this and then execute `pod install`:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<YOUR APP TARGET>' do

  # Firebase
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I updated question with my podfile, and i tried with your solution, but still same. It can't find Firebase.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me by updating cocoapods and my pod repo:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the approaches mentioned worked for me. Here is how I made it to work, however:

1. Comment out all of your pods in your `Podfile`.
2. Comment them back in
   one-by-one and run `pod install` after each
3. Clean and run

I hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

If it still doesn't work, remove cocoapods directory `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and re-setup cocoapods using `pod setup`

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes. If your cocoapod git repo is bad. This will work. Because my repo was not getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem.

what really worked for me was `gem uninstall cocoapods` where I found that I had 11 (!) cocoapods versions. I chose to uninstall all and then `gem install cocoapods:1.4.0`

All good now.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I just delete this row
if you are using unity and try to run for ios

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```