# I can't download Pod ParallaxHeader by Github

Tags: ios, github, swift3, cocoapods

My question is about an Pod of Github.

I have a problem with a version. I can't download it! :(

https://github.com/romansorochak/ParallaxHeader (I want version of Swift3 -> 1.0.6)

I tried this: `pod 'ParallaxHeader', '~> 1.0.6'`

But **Promt** shows this error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `ParallaxHeader (~> 1.0.6)`

Somebody knows whats happen??

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try the solutions posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102061/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-firebase-core

Comment: Show me your podfile  content

Comment: @Rushabh I attached podfile content in another answer ;) take a look please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue like that with these steps:

1. Open terminal.
2. Go to your project path.
3. Write:

   - pod repo update
   - pod install.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code in your pod file .I have checked it and I can able to download pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target ‘your project name’ do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for your project name

    pod 'ParallaxHeader', '~> 2.0.0'

end
```

Comment: Attached in another answer on top! Thanks