# Flutter error on pod install: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly"

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter app is not working on my iOS device, while it's working perfectly on Android. I'm getting an error on `pod install`.

This is the output of `pod install --verbose`:

```
alyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A contacts_service
  A firebase_auth
  A flutter_crashlytics
  A local_auth
  A onesignalflutter
  A path_provider
  A permission
  A sqflite
  A url_launcher
  - Flutter
  - OneSignal
  - cloud_functions
  - firebase_core

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_functions` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_functions/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `contacts_service` from `.symlinks/plugins/contacts_service/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `flutter_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_crashlytics/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `local_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/local_auth/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `onesignalflutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/onesignalflutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `permission` from `.symlinks/plugins/permission/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.20.2)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.0.0)

It seems like you've changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:91:in `resolve'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:909:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:907:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:114:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:266:in `analyze'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:174:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:173:in `resolve_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:136:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:48:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.6.1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `10.0` on target `OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

And this is my Podfile:

```
# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter packages get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignal', '>= 2.9.3', '< 3.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end

And this is my pubspec.yaml:

name: kvote_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_bloc: any
  color: any
  http: any
  equatable: any
#  permission_handler: ^2.1.2
  cloud_functions: ^0.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.0
  font_awesome_flutter: any
  fancy_bottom_navigation: any
  permission: any
  contacts_service: any
  local_auth: any
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: any
  auto_size_text: any
  flutter_crashlytics: any
  url_launcher: any
  rflutter_alert: any
  onesignalflutter:
        git: git://github.com/jmrobles/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK.git


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/avatar.png
  - assets/logo.png
  - assets/img/login_logo.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
  fonts:
    - family: WorkSansSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-SemiBold.ttf

    - family: WorkSansBold
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Bold.ttf

    - family: WorkSansMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-Medium.ttf
```

The error is happening mainly because of a conflict between cloud functions and authentication Firebase libraries.

I'm totally new to the pod, and can't seem to find a solution online of my case. I've tried the answer from *[Cocoapods: Unable to find a specification for `Firebase/Core`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102061/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-firebase-core/40102370#40102370)*, but it did not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055142/cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod-firebase-coreonly

Comment: Does it actually say *"[alyzing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analyse#Verb) dependencies"*?

Answer (score 16):

Go to your Flutter project. Navigate to "ios" and open Podfile. Replace the second line of that file with this:

`platform :ios, '10.0'`

*simple_permissions* doesn't work for iOS versions below 10.0.

Comment: Please be more specific about the line and make sure you are answering in full. We will have to down vote, unless you are correcting this... Good luck @Pierre

Comment: Here is the explanation https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4709#issuecomment-762296217

Comment: For me flutter upgrade and platform :ios, '12.0'

Answer (score 5):

Add the iOS version in the podfile at the top

```
platform :ios, '9.0' // ios/Pods/podfile
```

It specifies the minimum IOS version this pod project should support, And then install the pods using

```
pod install
```

And then try running the app.

Comment: Why does that work? How does it work? Are there some downsides?

Comment: What [line is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086585/flutter-error-on-pod-install-cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-p/66249992#66249992) it on...?

Comment: I understand the answer may not be detailed but not how it should be suggested for improvement. These kind of comments are the reason why people say stackoverflow is not nice to people.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me after delete Podfile.lock file and Pod directory, and again install pod manually using `pod install` command.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use these commands in the terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos  
pod setup
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed this from

```
platform :ios, '9.0' // ios/Pods/podfile
```

to

```
platform :ios, '10.0' // ios/Pods/podfile
```

And it worked for me.

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

You should not let [pubspec.yaml](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec) versions set to "any". After resolving the versions, you should fix it to have it stable.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after:

Step 1. Delete the *Podfile.lock* file and *Pod* directory

Step 2. `pod install --repo-update`

Step 3. `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just run this command, and it's fixed: `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an [Apple M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M2)-series Mac, you can resolve the issue by reconfiguring the pod files: run these commands.

**Clean the Flutter Build**

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get
>
> flutter upgrade

**Reinstall Pod files**

> cd ios
>
> pod cache clean --all
>
> Pod clean
>
> pod deintegrate
>
> sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
>
> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
>
> arch -x86_64 pod repo update
>
> arch -x86_64 pod install

Answer (score -2):

Simply uncommenting line 2 of Podfile worked for me.

Comment: Best to share what line 2 of the Podfile is for you as it could be different for people looking at this now or at a later date

Comment: include what is in the line 2?